# ROS Answers SE migration: Ad Hoc Network

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you use and Ad Hoc Network instead of a wireless network? The lab I work in is small so when it does the mapping program I can move around with workstation laptop. Or would having the connection be over BlueTooth be better?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39184/ad-hoc-network/) by [OakMan24](https://answers.ros.org/users/2808/oakman24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ad hoc network works fine. Just take note of the range of your laptop's WiFi. You may have to follow behind your robot with the laptop in hand while trying to stay away from the robot's view (if you are mapping the place for example)

I have not used bluetooth. I'm not sure how you would set the networks settings if you do.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0